# Error opening a zip file: No such file or directory?

Tags: macos, zip

After 25 years on PCs I am delighting in learning all I can about working with my new Mac and OS X Mavericks.

I tried just now to open a zip file but was interrupted with an Archive Utility dialog:

> Unable to expand "filename.zip" into "Downloads".
>   (Error 2 - No such file or directory.)

[image: Error 2 - No such file or directory.]

What to do? How can I access the contents of the zip file?

Answer (score 74):

It's likely that `filename.zip` is either not actually a `.zip` file, or is corrupted.

Open up **Terminal**. You can access it by typing "Terminal" into [Spotlight](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2531).

Enter the command(s) in the steps below into your command line prompt (triple click the line, copy it, and paste it into your prompt). Replace `filename.zip` with the actual name of the `zip` file.

If the name of the file contains spaces, you need to enter it differently using the escape `\` character. For example, if the file is named `compressed crap.zip`, you'd type `compressed\ crap.zip` in the command line.

### Step 1:

Repair disk permissions. Once done, attempt to open the .zip file again. If you wish, you can do this from the command line.

```
diskutil repairPermissions /
```

### Step 2:

Use [file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) to confirm it's actually a zip file:

```
file ~/Downloads/filename.zip
```

The output should be:
`Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`

If you don't receive this output, post the output as a comment before proceeding.

### Step 3:

After confirming it's actually a zip file, attempt to [unzip](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/unzip.1.html) it directly from the command line:

```
unzip ~/Downloads/filename.zip -d ~/Downloads
```

### Step 4:

Step 3 will likely fail. Run the [zip](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html) command to attempt to repair any corruption and salvage the contents of the archive (again, replace `filename.zip` with `actualname.zip`):

```
zip -FF ~/Downloads/filename.zip --out ~/Downloads/Repairedversion.zip
```

If it executes cleanly, you'll be directly returned to your prompt. Quit Terminal. Navigate to your Downloads folder and double click `Repairedversion.zip`- it should unzip without issue.

Alternatively, it may not exit cleanly. If you're presented with

`Is this a single-disk archive?  (y/n):`

Hit the `y` key. After you're returned to the prompt, again attempt to open `Repairedversion.zip` from your Downloads folder. If you're still unable to open it,  comment below with the warning(s) received from the command. If you've reached this point though, it's likely that the file is irreparably damaged.

Comment: You can also drag-n-drop the file into the terminal window, instead of typing the directory/filename. This also corrects automatically the optional spaces in the filename

Comment: Thanks for theses great instructions! I just tried steps 1-4. This is what I got when terminal finally choked on it. It was going along so well.. any help is greatly appreciated. Central Directory found... zip warning: Entry too big:Transmission/Zero.Dark.Thirty.2012.720p.BluRay.x264-Felony/f-zerodarkthirty.720p.mkv zip error: Entry too big to split, read, or write (Poor compression resulted in unexpectedly large entry - try -fz)

Comment: I'm receiving these errors:
`zip warning: no end of stream entry found: _file_inside_archive_`
`zip warning: rewinding and scanning for later entries`


Is there anything else that can be done to recover the archive's contents?

Comment: When trying the unzip step I got many unexpected replace <some path>? messages. Replacing them solved the problem. Something was rather wrong with the zip file.

Comment: @njboot, How exactly does the -FF fixes the file ?

Comment: @Pacerier from the man paged linked above `The -F option can be used if some portions of the  archive  are  missing, but  requires  a  reasonably intact central directory.  The input archive is scanned as usual, but zip will ignore some problems.  The resulting archive should be valid, but  any  inconsistent entries will be left out. When doubled  as  in -FF, the archive is scanned from the beginning and zip scans for special signatures to identify the limits between the archive members. If the  archive  is  too  damaged or the end has been truncated, you must use -FF.` Read the link for more.

Comment: @njboot, it gives me this error, 
Central Directory found...
Zip64 EOCDR found ( 1 28274105952)...
Zip64 EOCDL found ( 1 28274106008)...
EOCDR found ( 1 28274106028)...

I had password protected zip.

Comment: This no longer works on OS 10.13. `diskutil` no longer allows you to repair permissions

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could have happened here. The *easiest* way of resolving this is to re-download (or re-copy) the zip file from it's original source and re-try opening it up again. Without having more information, here's a list of possible things that could be happening:

- **The zip "folder" doesn't exist.** You wrote folder, but I'm assuming you meant file. What could happen is that you marked a normal, non-zip, file as a zip file by accidentally adding `.zip` to the end of the file name. So your computer thinks it is a zip file but it's not actually a zip file.
- **The destination doesn't exist.** From the error message, you might not actually have a `Downloads` folder.

All of these problems are non-intuitive and the fixes for them are equally non-intuitive and technical. I think your best bet is trying to re-acquire the file again.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with an app other than Archive Utility, which is the unarchiver built in to macOS.

I used the app [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/). It too encountered an error:

> Extraction of "filename.zip" failed
>   Error code 2 using "p7zip"
>   Fatal error

However it also *was able to unzip* a directory that contained 6 complete image files, along with a 7th failed "Zero bytes" image that failed extraction.

Using this app, or some other 3rd party unzipping app, you may be able to recover at least some of the files from the corrupted archive.